# _mkdir strange behaviour c++

Tags: c++, file, directory, mkdir

I'm struggling with a strange issue.
I want to create a folder for the solution of my program and I've written the following code:

```
timer = time(NULL);
path.assign(".\\Solution_");
path.append(ctime(&timer));
ch1 = ':';
ch2 = '_';
for (i = 0; i < path.length(); ++i) {
    if (path[i] == ch1 || path[i] == ' ')
    path[i] = ch2;
    }

mkdir(path.c_str());
```

it doesn't create anything even if **path** is equal to "*.\Solution_Thu_Jun_12_10_10_31_2014*" and if I type

```
mkdir(".\\test");
```

It works correctly.
I did many test and I ckeck all I could but I cannot figure out what's wrong.
Can anyone help me please?
Best,
Roberto

Detail:
Even if I use `mkdir(path.c_str());` with path equal to "Solution_Thu_Jun_12_11_52_04_2014" (without any \) it doesn't work anyway and on the other side 'mkdir("test");' works.

**Solution**: 
Ok there was a hidden newline.
Thanks everyone for the help :-)!!!

Comment: Are you running on an embedded system? IIRC mkdir is not part of the standard.

Comment: The issue is due to escaping via the backslash `\ `.  Doing `.\\Solution...` should work.

Comment: what is outputed when `cout path.cstr()` right before your `mkdir(path.c_str());` ? Does it work fine if you replace `mkdir(".\\test");` with `mkdir(".\\Solution_Thu_Jun_12_10_10_31_2014");` ?

Comment: @graham.reeds I'm running on win Vista

Comment: Have you considered checking the return value? and errno?

Comment: @Ploutox the output is .\Solution_Thu_Jun_12_10_41_37_2014 and it works absolutely fine with mkdir (".\\test") and with mkdir(".\\Solution_Thu_Jun_12_10_10_31_2014");

Comment: Put `cout << path[i] << "-";` after `if` in the `for loop` to check if there is any illegal character in the path

Comment: @smttsp the characters are correct there's just an endline at the end (I've a minus in a new line). Maybe is that the problem?!

Comment: "endline at the end": this is bad.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that the backslash character is the start of an escape sequence.  These were used to input a non-printable character into the stream (tabs, carriage returns, etc.).

So your program is seeing a backslash and expecting that the next character will be a command character. If it sees another backslash then it knows that you want a backslash and not an escape sequence, hence why \\ works and \ doesn't.

Since you are running a flavour of Windows you could use [CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Also what you have put as your example is C, not C++.  What source are you learning from?

Comment: Yeah, it's C... the environment I'm using is the MS Visual C++ express edition. It was just misleading :-)

Comment: I don't want to use CreateDirectory function and I didn't get what you say "... hence why \ works and \ doesn't." 
Which is the workaround you suggest?

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that eve if I use 'mkdir(path.c_str());' with path equal to "Solution_Thu_Jun_12_11_52_04_2014" (without any \) it doesn't work anyway and 'mkdir("test");' works.

Comment: The double back slash was stripping one of the backslashes out due to it being an escape sequence:-) Had to put 4 backslasshes in.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is newline or any other illegal character for filename in windows. Your error looks like that.

windows doesn't allow these character `<>?/\| or newline` in filename